# Ajuda com condição para montar layout csv com php

Tags: php, csv

Estou gerando um .CSV para uma importação onde ele esta me retornando os dados como podem ver nesse gist:
 https://gist.github.com/otaciobarbosa/b1b442816ec95ff570d6d5c70e8b1f64

O que acontece é que eu tenho 2 linhas de tratamento:

```
 1: M;123;CSV PRODUCAO;22/05/2017 
 2: *P;30080 ;7891 ;180;163,74 ;160;30080  JOAO SILVA ;2 ;;;22/05/2017 ;;;123
```

A numero 1 é o cabeçalho do bloco.

A numero 2 seria as linhas.

Como pode ver no final do cabeçalho e da linha tem um data, o que preciso, quando as duas datas forem iguais,não repetir o cabeçalho.
 Como podem ver no codigo esperado do gist.

O motivo de estar fazendo isso é que estou pegando um outro csv, importando , e tratando para gerar um outro layoult.

No gist também tem o upload.php onde estou fazendo tudo, alguém poderia me ajudar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resposta @-Kelver (de outra comunidade):

faz

```
$dataAuxiliar = '';

if($dataAuxiliar != $VarData){

faz o q tem q fazer....

}

no fechamento do loop alimenta a $dataAuxiliar = $VarData;
```