# Erro ao tentar salvar txt

Tags: php, csv, txt

Pessoal bom dia,
 Tenho esse bloco de código:

```
$delimitador    = ';';
$cerca          = '"';
$VarDataAux     = '';
// Abrir arquivo para leitura
$f = fopen($_FILES['arquivo']['tmp_name'], 'r');
if ($f) {

    // Ler cabecalho do arquivo
    $cabecalho = fgetcsv($f, 0, $delimitador, $cerca);

    // Enquanto nao terminar o arquivo
    while (!feof($f)) {

        // Ler uma linha do arquivo
        $linha = fgetcsv($f, 0, $delimitador, $cerca);
        if (!$linha) {
            continue;
        }

        // Montar registro com valores indexados pelo cabecalho
        $registro = array_combine($cabecalho, $linha);

        $VarLoja      =  $registro['loja'].PHP_EOL;
        $VarData      =  $registro['Dtemi'].PHP_EOL;
        $VarDoc       =  $registro['Doc'].PHP_EOL;
        $VarFonec     =  $registro['Forn'].PHP_EOL;
        $VarNFornec   =  $registro['Nforn'].PHP_EOL;
        $VarCodCont   =  $registro['Codcont'].PHP_EOL;
        $VarValorN    =  $registro['Vlnota'].PHP_EOL;
        $VarValorInss =  $registro['Inss'].PHP_EOL;

        $VarDocFinal =  str_pad($VarDoc,8, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);

if($VarDataAux != $VarData){
  echo $VarCabecalho =  "M;".$VarLote.";CSV PRODUCAO;".$VarData.PHP_EOL;
  echo $VarLinha =  "*P;".$VarDoc.";".$VarCodCont.";180;".$VarValorInss.";160;".$VarDocFinal." ".$VarNFornec.";".$VarLoja.";;;".$VarData.";;;".$VarLote.PHP_EOL;
}else{
  echo $VarLinha =  "*P;".$VarDoc.";".$VarCodCont.";180;".$VarValorInss.";160;".$VarDocFinal." ".$VarNFornec.";".$VarLoja.";;;".$VarData.";;;".$VarLote.PHP_EOL;
     }

     $VarDataAux = $VarData;

     $name = 'TESTE.txt';
     $text = $VarCabecalho.$VarLinha;
     $file = fopen($name, 'a');
     fwrite($file, $text);
     fclose($file);

   }
  fclose($f);

}
```

Ele recebe um arquivo csv e trata algumas informações e cria o layout.
Até ai ta rodando tudo certo, eu vou no navegador e ele ta blza, como tem que ser, exemplo:

```
M;4444;CSV PRODUCAO;02/06/2017 
*P;30318 ; ;180;25,81 ;160;030318 JOAO DA SILVA ;2 ;;;02/06/2017 ;;;4444 
M;4444;CSV PRODUCAO;05/06/2017 
*P;30359 ; ;180;4,34 ;160;030359 JOAO DA SILVA ;2 ;;;05/06/2017 ;;;4444 
M;4444;CSV PRODUCAO;06/06/2017 
*P;30364 ; ;180;15,95 ;160;030364 JOAO DA SILVA ;2 ;;;06/06/2017 ;;;4444 
M;4444;CSV PRODUCAO;07/06/2017 
*P;30393 ; ;180;4,37 ;160;030393 JOAO DA SILVA ;2 ;;;07/06/2017 ;;;4444 
M;4444;CSV PRODUCAO;12/06/2017 
*P;30480 ; ;180;19,53 ;160;030480 JOAO DA SILVA ;2 ;;;12/06/2017 ;;;4444 
M;4444;CSV PRODUCAO;16/06/2017 
*P;30529 ; ;180;25,4 ;160;030529 JOAO DA SILVA ;2 ;;;16/06/2017 ;;;4444 
M;4444;CSV PRODUCAO;19/06/2017 
*P;30562 ; ;180;6,75 ;160;030562 JOAO DA SILVA ;2 ;;;19/06/2017 ;;;4444 
M;4444;CSV PRODUCAO;20/06/2017 
*P;30594 ; ;180;15,98 ;160;030594 JOAO DA SILVA ;2 ;;;20/06/2017 ;;;4444 
M;4444;CSV PRODUCAO;22/06/2017 
*P;30620 ; ;180;11,04 ;160;030620 JOAO DA SILVA ;2 ;;;22/06/2017 ;;;4444 
*P;30624 ; ;180;4,94 ;160;030624 JOAO DA SILVA ;2 ;;;22/06/2017 ;;;4444 
*P;30626 ; ;180;14,03 ;160;030626 JOAO DA SILVA ;2 ;;;22/06/2017 ;;;4444
```

Mais como podem ver estou exportando ele para um txt nessa parte:

```
 $name = 'TESTE.txt';
 $text = $VarCabecalho.$VarLinha;
 $file = fopen($name, 'a');
 fwrite($file, $text);
 fclose($file);
```

Só que no meu txt esse ta exportando errado, esta exportando assim:

```
;180;4,34
;160;030359
 JOAO DA SILVA                 
;2
;;;05/06/2017
;;;4444
M;4444;CSV PRODUCAO;06/06/2017

*P;30364
;              
;180;15,95
;160;030364
 JOAO DA SILVA                 
;2
;;;06/06/2017
;;;4444
M;4444;CSV PRODUCAO;07/06/2017

*P;30393
;              
;180;4,37
;160;030393
 JOAO DA SILVA                 
;2
;;;07/06/2017
;;;4444
M;4444;CSV PRODUCAO;12/06/2017

*P;30480
;              
;180;19,53
;160;030480
 JOAO DA SILVA                 
;2
;;;12/06/2017
;;;4444
M;4444;CSV PRODUCAO;16/06/2017

*P;30529
;              
;180;25,4
;160;030529
 JOAO DA SILVA                 
;2
;;;16/06/2017
;;;4444
```

A primeira linha esta respeitando ok, só que as demais ele ta quebrando nos ; eu preciso que ta mesma forma que esta no navegador saia no txt.

Recebo o csv assim:

```
loja;Dtemi;Doc;Forn;Nforn;Codcont;Vlnota;Inss
2;02/06/2017;30318;  7688/0;JOAO DA SILVA                 ;              ;1.122,40;25,81
2;05/06/2017;30359;  7688/0;JOAO DA SILVA                 ;              ;188,7;4,34
2;06/06/2017;30364;  7688/0;JOAO DA SILVA                 ;              ;693,6;15,95
2;07/06/2017;30393;  7688/0;JOAO DA SILVA                 ;              ;190,4;4,37
2;12/06/2017;30480;  7688/0;JOAO DA SILVA                 ;              ;849,4;19,53
2;16/06/2017;30529;  7688/0;JOAO DA SILVA                 ;              ;1.104,60;25,4
2;19/06/2017;30562;  7688/0;JOAO DA SILVA                 ;              ;293,84;6,75
2;20/06/2017;30594;  7688/0;JOAO DA SILVA                 ;              ;694,8;15,98
2;22/06/2017;30620;  7688/0;JOAO DA SILVA                 ;              ;480;11,04
2;22/06/2017;30624;  7688/0;JOAO DA SILVA                 ;              ;214,8;4,94
2;22/06/2017;30626;  7688/0;JOAO DA SILVA                 ;              ;610;14,03
```

Preciso entregar o txt assim:

```
M;4444;CSV PRODUCAO;16/06/2017 
*P;30529 ; ;180;25,4 ;160;030529 JOAO DA SILVA ;2 ;;;16/06/2017 ;;;4444 
M;4444;CSV PRODUCAO;19/06/2017 
*P;30562 ; ;180;6,75 ;160;030562 JOAO DA SILVA ;2 ;;;19/06/2017 ;;;4444 
M;4444;CSV PRODUCAO;20/06/2017 
*P;30594 ; ;180;15,98 ;160;030594 JOAO DA SILVA ;2 ;;;20/06/2017 ;;;4444 
M;4444;CSV PRODUCAO;22/06/2017 
*P;30620 ; ;180;11,04 ;160;030620 JOAO DA SILVA ;2 ;;;22/06/2017 ;;;4444 
*P;30624 ; ;180;4,94 ;160;030624 JOAO DA SILVA ;2 ;;;22/06/2017 ;;;4444 
*P;30626 ; ;180;14,03 ;160;030626 JOAO DA SILVA ;2 ;;;22/06/2017 ;;;4444
```

Comment: Quando cria as variáveis a partir dos dados em `$registro`, por quê adiciona o `PHP_EOL` no final? É isso que está quebrando a linha.

Comment: Ja melhorou, mais só que fazendo dessa forma ele não esta mais respeito essa condição: if($VarDataAux != $VarData){ como poderia gravar esse retorno todo em uma unica variável ? acho que resolveria.

Comment: Se `$VarDataAux` recebe $`VarData`, não entendo porque iria fazer diferença na condição. Não sei bem o que esse `if` faz, mas você pode tentar adicionar o `PHP_EOL` neste `if`, se é o problema, ou fazer o `trim` da outra variável. É difícil dizer sem saber o que o código deveria fazer, de fato.

Comment: O if e por esse motivo: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/216797/ajuda-com-condi%C3%A7%C3%A3o-para-montar-layout-csv-com-php

Comment: Ok, tudo faz mais sentido agora. Sempre haverá uma linha de cabeçalho antes da linha de dados?

Comment: O que é `$VarLote`? Por quê essa variável é usada, mas não está definida? E por quê quando vai escrever no TXT você possui `$VarCabecalho.$VarLinha`? Isso escreverá o cabeçalho sempre, mas não é isso que você quer.

Comment: Ele vem de um post, e como se fosse uma referencia do usuário, é um numero, exemplo: 123 ou 456.

Comment: Sobre: $VarCabecalho.$VarLinha é porque segui a linha de uma outra pessoa, mais se tiver errado pode alterar, preciso como no exemplo mesmo, se a data for igual só exibir o cabeçalho 1 vez, como nesse bloco da pergunta (Preciso entregar o txt assim )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A minha ideia inicial era responder com um código mais estruturado e melhor de entender, mas você não facilitou as coisas. Muitas informações omitidas e sempre cada vez mais confuso, então as alterações que precisa fazer para funcionar são:

1. Remover os `PHP_EOL` como sugerido nos comentários;

   ```
   $VarLoja      =  $registro['loja'];
   $VarData      =  $registro['Dtemi'];
   $VarDoc       =  $registro['Doc'];
   $VarFonec     =  $registro['Forn'];
   $VarNFornec   =  $registro['Nforn'];
   $VarCodCont   =  $registro['Codcont'];
   $VarValorN    =  $registro['Vlnota'];
   $VarValorInss =  $registro['Inss'];
   ```
2. Corrigir o texto que é gravado no arquivo TXT. Ter `$text = $VarCabecalho.$VarLinha` sempre fará gravar a linha de cabeçalho antes de todas as linhas e você não quer isso. Como você disse nos comentários, você fez isso baseado na lógica de outra pessoa e possivelmente não entendeu o que fez. Então coloque `$text` dentro do `if` e remova este errado;

   ```
   if($VarDataAux != $VarData){
     echo $VarCabecalho =  "M;".$VarLote.";CSV PRODUCAO;".$VarData.PHP_EOL;
     echo $VarLinha =  "*P;".$VarDoc.";".$VarCodCont.";180;".$VarValorInss.";160;".$VarDocFinal." ".$VarNFornec.";".$VarLoja.";;;".$VarData.";;;".$VarLote.PHP_EOL;
     $text = $VarCabecalho.$VarLinha;
   }else{
     echo $VarLinha =  "*P;".$VarDoc.";".$VarCodCont.";180;".$VarValorInss.";160;".$VarDocFinal." ".$VarNFornec.";".$VarLoja.";;;".$VarData.";;;".$VarLote.PHP_EOL;
     $text = $VarLinha;
   }
   ```

Com isso, seu TXT deve ser gerado assim:

```
M;;CSV PRODUCAO;02/06/2017
*P;30318;              ;180;25,81;160;00030318 JOAO DA SILVA                 ;2;;;02/06/2017;;;
M;;CSV PRODUCAO;05/06/2017
*P;30359;              ;180;4,34;160;00030359 JOAO DA SILVA                 ;2;;;05/06/2017;;;
M;;CSV PRODUCAO;06/06/2017
*P;30364;              ;180;15,95;160;00030364 JOAO DA SILVA                 ;2;;;06/06/2017;;;
M;;CSV PRODUCAO;07/06/2017
*P;30393;              ;180;4,37;160;00030393 JOAO DA SILVA                 ;2;;;07/06/2017;;;
M;;CSV PRODUCAO;12/06/2017
*P;30480;              ;180;19,53;160;00030480 JOAO DA SILVA                 ;2;;;12/06/2017;;;
M;;CSV PRODUCAO;16/06/2017
*P;30529;              ;180;25,4;160;00030529 JOAO DA SILVA                 ;2;;;16/06/2017;;;
M;;CSV PRODUCAO;19/06/2017
*P;30562;              ;180;6,75;160;00030562 JOAO DA SILVA                 ;2;;;19/06/2017;;;
M;;CSV PRODUCAO;20/06/2017
*P;30594;              ;180;15,98;160;00030594 JOAO DA SILVA                 ;2;;;20/06/2017;;;
M;;CSV PRODUCAO;22/06/2017
*P;30620;              ;180;11,04;160;00030620 JOAO DA SILVA                 ;2;;;22/06/2017;;;
*P;30624;              ;180;4,94;160;00030624 JOAO DA SILVA                 ;2;;;22/06/2017;;;
*P;30626;              ;180;14,03;160;00030626 JOAO DA SILVA                 ;2;;;22/06/2017;;;
```

> Defini `$VarLote = ""` para não gerar alertas, visto que esta variável foi omitida completamente da pergunta. Por isso o resultado não possui tal valor.

Se não for essa a saída desejada, é melhor você excluir a pergunta e criá-la de novo, mas de uma forma compreensível e completa, com todas as informações, incluindo um exemplo mínimo, completo e verificável.

Comment: A dica : solucionou meu problema, gravou da forma que precisa, Obrigado. $text = $VarLinha;